# Conditional model binding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to create a calendar that has a default template of 'available hours' in a day, and will allow the user to edit any particular day to an assigned number of hours.

So basically:

**TEAM 1:**
Sunday: 8
Monday: 8
Tuesday: 8
Wednesday: 8
Thursday: 8
Friday: 8
Saturday: 8

I have edited the angularUI Bootstrap Datepicker directive to allow me to create a datepicker with an input box under each day that will show the current hours available for that day and allow the user to enter a custom value.

I currently store the default template in the database for each team, and I have another table that is DATE and HOURS. That table is used to check if the date they are requesting has additional hours allotted or should use the default template.

I can make all this work on the server side, but making it work in the client is escaping me.

I need to populate the values of the datepicker input boxes with the default template values unless a value for that date exists in the custom table. I can actually make this work, but my problem comes in when I try to edit any of this. If I set the ng-model to the custom template, it will only bind on dates where there is an entry. If I don't set the model, I don't know how to add an entry to my custom object for that date.

Here is a plunk that shows what happens if I try to model bind:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker default-hours="vm.defaultHours" show-weeks="false" ng-model="controller.dt" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
</div>
```

**(you have to click on a date to enable editing of that days hours)**

http://plnkr.co/edit/l1gSNuKd4EY35qha1Xl0?p=preview

You can see that the only day that shows an entry is the one with a value in the customTemplate attribute(line 68 of customBootstrap.js)

And here is a plunk that shows how I can display either the default template or custom template hours, but I don't know how to update that custom object when I change a value:

**(you have to click on a date to enable editing of that days hours)**

http://plnkr.co/edit/pZh5L4ztUuhDkZZDZCfX?p=preview

If you can think of a better way to go about this, I'm also open to suggestions, but I need to be able to have a default template, and allow specific date configurations (preferably without having to make a database entry for every date for every team).

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Well, it turns out you can actually just use a conditional on ng-model. I really didn't even think of that let alone that I'd be able to. This might solve my problems.

Comment: Well, it shows the correct values anyway, but I can't edit it and I get an error...I'll keep researching